# httpd.service failed despite config being valid (error: AH00016: Configuration Failed)

Tags: apache, flask

Recently I've been having an error starting my httpd service for my apache server that serves my Flask app. It's running on an AWS EC2 instance. It was working last week, then I tried to add SSL to my server and it wasn't immediately working. It wasn't a big deal so I decided to stick with regular HTTP for now because I'm in a hurry. Now however I'm getting the following error with no useful logging information:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-06-13 01:10:05 UTC; 15s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 2298 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2298 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."

Jun 13 01:10:05 ip-172-31-40-174.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 13 01:10:05 ip-172-31-40-174.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exit...RE
Jun 13 01:10:05 ip-172-31-40-174.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 13 01:10:05 ip-172-31-40-174.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 13 01:10:05 ip-172-31-40-174.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

This is my `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     WSGIDaemonProcess ocr_api python-path=/var/www/html/ocr_api:/var/www/html/ocr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
     ServerName ******
     WSGIScriptAlias /ocr_api /var/www/html/ocr_api/api.wsgi
      
     <Directory /var/www/html/ocr_api/>
         Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog custom_logs/ocr_error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

When running `sudo httpd -t` I get `Syntax OK` so I'm not sure what exactly apache is having an issue with??

When I check the error log I see this: `AH00016: Configuration Failed`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out the problem, for anyone who comes here in the future I ininitally neglected to check the ssl logs under `/etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log` which displayed the error:
`AH02565: Certificate and private key ip-172-**-**-**.us-east-, 2.compute.internal:443:0 from /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt and /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key do not match`

So I regenerated the self-signed certs like so:
`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt`  - [reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/648534/accidently-removed-localhost-crt-ssl-in-centos-6-what-can-i-do)

Now it is working.